# Google Cloud Storage on local development Server: Invalid Filename

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to "upload" a byte array to the local GAE/J (1.8.1, Eclipse Juno) development Server using Google Cloud Storage Client Library:

```
byte[] byteContent = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("MyBucket", "foo");
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel =
GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService().createOrReplace(fileName, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
outputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(byteContent));
outputChannel.close();
```

Attempting this, the following Exception is thrown:

```
WARNING: Caught IOException while attempting to write blob
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\workspace\gaeTestProjekt\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\encoded_gs_key:L2dzL015QnVja2V0L2Zvbw (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Which makes sense given the existence of an additional colon in the name of the target file (encoded_gs_key:L2dzL015QnVja2V0L2Zvbw).

Question is, how do I prevent the local development Server from attempting to create an invalid filename ?

Comment: Which os are you using? I'm using windows 7 64-bit and the files are saved on disk but are not browsable by the windows shell nor by the command prompt.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Any updates on the issue?

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the source of the error. If I run the development server inside a truecrypt drive the error occurs. If I run it outside the error is gone. So it seems to be a problem with how truecrypt is handling files.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to maybe dig around here [enable file name character translation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289627)

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the filesystem type. I keep my files on usb disk which is FAT32 for compatibility. After I changed to NTFS everything works now. What a nasty little bug.

PS. @Andre's answer inspired me. I can't imagine what he has gone through to find that out.